# jQuery .Click() Function not firing more than one time

Tags: jquery

So I have written an HTML page that when a name is clicked, that name fades out.
The code looks something like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#names").click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p id = "names">John Doe</p>
<p id = "names">Jane Doe</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Every time I run it I can only click one name... I would like to be able to click every name so that they all disappear... Any suggestions??

Comment: ids must be unique on the page. You cannot have more than one element with the same id.

Comment: For a little bit more information, check out this write-up: https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Answer (score 4):

you're improperly using the an html `id` attribute. if you have multiple entries, you need to use a `class` attribute, not an id. `$("#names")` will only grab the first element selected and apply the event listener to it.

you want to convert it to a class, so that all elements are applied the listener

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".names").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="names">John Doe</p>
<p class="names">Jane Doe</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have unique ID for the elements.

When ever you are writing a generic code that must act on many elements **use class** to make the life simpler.

Sample snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".names").click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p class = "names">John Doe</p>
<p class = "names">Jane Doe</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Reason for your current behaviour : when ever you use `$('#name')` the Jquery will select only the first element with that id parsing from top of the DOM.. hence you had the event only binded to the first element. Change it to use class which will result in selecting all the elements with specified class..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use duplicate ID in a single page. It's not valid. Use class instead.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".names").click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p class = "names">John Doe</p>
<p class = "names">Jane Doe</p>

</body>
</html>
```